Puse in iframe en una web echo en wordpres, y ahora quiero obtener los parametros de la url padre
en mi iframe tengo esta función para obtener los parametros de mi url padre que vendria ser el del wordpres
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.parent.location.search);  
    const roomType = params.get('roomType');
    console.log('Room type from parent URL:', roomType); 

    if (roomType) {
      resource.type = roomType;
    } else {
      resource.type = 'S';
    }


En su tiempo intenté lo que quieres hacer y pues, la única opción viable y posible fue actualizar los parámetros desde el sistema padre, tener todo listo en la URL del iframe antes renderizarlo y ahí sí funcionó como esperaba. Saludos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
